# difference between intent.setClass() and intent.setComponent()

Tags: android, android-intent

I am looking at a tutorial and see the author using intent.setClass() to get the to the next Activity and then on the same page he uses `intent.setComponent()` to get to the next Activity.

So what is the difference and what is the advantage in using any of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than different parameters.

`intent.setcomponent()` = Explicitly set the component to do the handling of the intent.

`intent.setClass()` = Convenience for calling setComponent(ComponentName) with the name returned by a Class object.

another difference is that `.setComponent()` can find the appropiate class for you.

****From android Developers****

[SetComponent Android Dev](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setComponent%28android.content.ComponentName%29)

You should only set this value when you know you absolutely want a specific class to be used; otherwise it is better to let the system find the appropriate class so that you will respect the installed applications and user preferences.